# Windows App in Win32 with multiple menu bars?

Tags: c++, winapi, menu, mfc

I am working on designing a relatively heavy app for windows that will work in multiple windows (each can be in docked/undocked modes).

So far, the development of the app has been done in the Win32 framework but it feels like that the look of the app cannot be modernized further than a certain limit.

We, specifically have a problem adding menu items to children windows when they are in docked mode. They can have the menu items but they will look weird with a blue windows-XP style frame when they become children in docked mode.

Is there a way to remove this blue frame and also close, maximize/minimize buttons but keep the menubar for children's windows in Win32 API?

This is the minimal code of how I am making a window a child window:

```
ShowWindow(hParentWindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
SetParent(hChildWindow, hParentWindow);
MoveWindow(hChildWindow, 0, 0, width2, length2, true); //Moving Child window inside the parent        
RedrawWindow(hChildWindow, nullptr, nullptr, RDW_INVALIDATE);
ShowWindow(hChildWindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This way I will have the menu bar in the child window but it will also have the blueish frame and close maximize that I dont want. If I change the style of the child window with the following code, it will no longer have the bluish frame but it will also lose its menubar:

```
SetWindowLong(hChildWindow, GWL_STYLE,  CHILD_STYLES);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [You cannot assign a menu to a child window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenu). Whatever you are doing does not match your description. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I added a picture that the child window still has the menu bars. It just looks weird with that blue frame that I cannot get rid of.

Comment: Again, please show a [mcve]. And since you skipped over it, please take the [tour]. Also make sure to read [ask].

Comment: added some reproducible codes. Hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: [`WS_CHILD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) - The window is a child window. A window with this style cannot have a menu bar. And `SetParent` does not modify the window styles of the window whose parent is being changed. If `hWndNewParent` is not `NULL` set the `WS_CHILD` style before calling [`SetParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent#remarks).

Answer (score 0):

Your windows have a frame when not being docked.  You must remove the frame by using a combination of GetWindowLong() AND SetWindowLong()

Example:

```
LONG lExStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

lStyle &= ~(WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION);
lExStye &= ~(WS_EX_MDICHILD | WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);

SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
```

The flags depend of course on the effect you want, and this form of sequence should be done when undocking as well, using bitwise AND and OR to set/reset flags.

The 'blue frame' is indicative of an MDI child windows, or an overlapped window being the child of a child window.

Comment: Amazing...
Thanks, it works like a charm  
Also, do you know if there is any built-in button for dock/undock inside Win32?
(added image in my original post)

Comment: No, there is not.  You must add the 'pin' bitmap to your resources.   To add the buttton to your frame, You must have owner-drawn title bars.